# Group By just one column Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql query where I select several columns, like this:

```
select * from(
select date_trunc('hour', o.timeofday), count(o.userid),
case when o.userid in(select o.userid from tableOne  where columnA = 'somevalue' group by userid)
Then(
'This equals some value'
)
Else 'some other value'
End as columnB
from tableOne o
inner join tableTwo t
on o.userid = t.userid
where t.columnC = 'someValue'
group by o.userid, t.columnC, date_trunc('hour', o.timeofday)
order by columnD) x
where columnB = 'someValue'
```

The result is something like this:

```
date_trunc | count | columnB
timestamp1     1
timestamp1     1
timestamp1     1
timestamp1     1
timestamp2     1
timestamp2     1
```

And I want something like this:

```
date_trunc | count | columnB
timestamp1    4
timestamp2    2
```

I know why I'm getting all '1' in the count column. It's because I'm grouping by multiple things, and I would achieve the results I want if I only grouped by 'date_trunc('hour', o.timeofday)'. But if I remove everything else in the `group by` clause I get an error saying I need to group by those other columns too. Is there a way I can group by just the date_trunc and if so, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the time for the key column, then only use the time expression in the `group by`.  The rest of the columns are unnecessary.  As is the subquery:

```
select date_trunc('hour', o.timeofday), count(o.userid),
       (case when o.userid in (select o.userid from tableOne where columnA = 'somevalue' group by userid)
            Then 'This equals some value'
            Else 'some other value'
        End) as columnB
from tableOne o inner join
     tableTwo t
     on o.userid = t.userid
where t.columnC = 'someValue'
group by date_trunc('hour', o.timeofday)
having columnB = 'someValue'
order by ??;  -- there is no `ColumnD` defined in the query
```